# what is the opposite of cynical?

Tags: american-english, antonyms

How would you describe a person who is the total opposite of cynical?
I thought of 'idealistic' or 'straightforward' but they don't seem right.

Comment: Either ***naive***, or something in its constellation of synonyms (eg *ingenuous*).

Comment: A few antonyms are: trusting, believing and undoubting.

Comment: @DanBron That's an answer.

Comment: @bib, for GR questions, I tend to leave comments, rather than just copy/paste the dictionary as an answer.

Comment: @DanBron I think it's more than general reference. There are subtle differences among the proposed terms and I think your is best. These questions and answers can be even better with a discussion of the connotative meanings, not just the definitions.

Comment: @bib, that sounds like a lot of work, but if you'd like to propose naive or ingenuous as an answer and elaborate a bit on the subtleties, please feel free to do so! You won't be stepping on my toes.

Answer (score 2):

*Cynical* can be used in different contexts. Some example sentences of its *synonyms* ...

- I’m rather *skeptical* about his chances of winning despite what the paper say.
- It is *ironic* that she became a teacher, she used to hate school when she was a girl.
- I think the original sales figures were too *pessimistic*.
- People who don’t like him said he was very *sarcastic*.

[Cynical -sentence usage examples](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/cynical)

***Antonyms***: Credulous,gullible,hopeful,optimistic,trustful,unskeptical,unsuspecting (etc.)

- He must have been pretty *gullible* to fall for that old trick.
- I feel *hopeful* that we’ll find a suitable house very soon.
- She is not *optimistic* about the outcome.
- He had crept upon his *unsuspecting* victim from behind

Comment: I think cynical is like sarcastic in that they imply a slightly mocking/contemptuous attitude. It is the opposite of *this* I am looking for, rather than simply if something is believed or not.
In any case I'll award this the answer if nothing better comes up...

Comment: opposite of slightly or opposite of mocking?

Answer (score 1):

*gullible*

> Easily persuaded to believe something; *credulous*

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gullible

Synonyms:

> credulous, over-trusting, over-trustful, trustful, easily deceived/led, easily taken in, exploitable, dupable, deceivable, impressionable, unsuspecting, unsuspicious, unwary, unguarded, unsceptical, ingenuous, naive, innocent, simple, inexperienced, unworldly, green, as green as grass, childlike, ignorant; foolish, silly

informal

> wet behind the ears, born yesterday

gullible vs credulous

> A gullible person is easy to deceive because they are too ready to believe or trust someone ( *professional manipulators intent on pulling the wool over the eyes of a gullible public*). They are particularly likely to believe something that would be to their advantage or that they want to be true. Gullible carries a note of scornful pity at someone's foolish failure to examine the evidence critically. Credulous also describes people who are too ready to believe or accept what they are told ( *the very incomprehensibility of the modern world has made us even more credulous*), but, unlike gullible, credulous does not necessarily imply that anyone is deliberately trying to take advantage of an easily-fooled person.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/gullible#gullible__1